# Contains doesn't make a difference between "Level 1-1" and "Level 1-11" in my List<string>

Tags: c#

I have the following items in my List:

Leaderboard Level 1-11 Ticket

Leaderboard Level 1-1 Ticket

Now, I want to check if there is an item in the list that contains the string "Level 1-1".

The problem is that *if (ticketslist[i].Contains(name))* is true if the item is "Leaderboard Level 1-11 Ticket" and "Leaderboard Level 1-1 Ticket". But I only want that *if (ticketslist[i].Contains(name))* is true if the item is "Leaderboard Level 1-1 Ticket".

What can I do so that *if (ticketslist[i].Contains(name))* is only true when the item is "Leaderboard Level 1-1 Ticket"?

```
  List<string> ticketslist = new List<string>();
  ticketslist.Add("Leaderboard Level 1-11 Ticket");
  ticketslist.Add("Leaderboard Level 1-1 Ticket");
  string ticket = string.Empty;
  string name = "Level 1-1";

  for (int i = 0; i <= ticketslist.Count - 1; i++)
  {
    if (ticketslist[i].Contains(name))
    {
      ticket = ticketslist[i];
      break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: The problem is, that `"Level 1-11"` contains `"Level 1-1"`. The best way to solve this problem is to use Regex for the string comparison. A simpler, but less clean way, is to add a space to `"Level 1-1"` so that you end up with this: `"Level 1-1 "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Regular Expression to detect it like this:

`if (Regex.IsMatch(ticketslist[i], @"\b" + Regex.Escape(name) + @"\b"))`

This would do exactly as you described, however this regex only get's you so far, if you need to detect something like `Level 1-` then it would trigger again since that would hold true for both cases again.

I suggest you give it a shot and depending on what you need from the regex, there are good sites that help you build regular expressions and let's you see the results live.

Comment: Be careful, because if `name` contains any regex pattern it could produce unwanted results. For instance, if `name` is `test[john]` it would not match the string `test[john]`

Comment: `$@"\b{Regex.Escape(name)}\b}"` would be safer.

Comment: True, only thought of the written case there, I'll update the answer.

Comment: The string name will only have values like: Level 1-1, Level 1-2,..., Level 1-10, Level 1-11,... The string name will never have values like: Level 1, Level 1-, Level -1, Level -1-1.

Comment: @Bill_Johnson77 then that should work perfectly fine for you